# is it possible to send mails programmatically with imap protocol?

Tags: android, imap, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to send an email programmatically, from a microsoft exchange account. is this possible through the imap protocol, if so how, i cant find any guide on this. Or do i need to use the smtp for this.

what i tried so far:

```
public MailSender() {
    host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
    hunterHost = "exchange.ictum.nl";

    port = "465"; // default smtp port
    hunterPort = "587";

    sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    user = ""; // username
    pass = ""; // password
    from = ""; // email sent from
    subject = ""; // email subject
    body = ""; // email body

    debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}

public MailSender(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    this.user = user;
    this.pass = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if (!user.equals("") && !pass.equals("") && to.length > 0 && !from.equals("") && !subject.equals("") && !body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(body);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(multipart);

        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addAttachment(String fileLocation, String fileName) throws Exception {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileLocation);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileLocation);
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);

    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "imaps");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", hunterHost);

    props.put("mail.imaps.user", user);
    props.put("mail.imaps.host", hunterHost);

    props.put("mail.imaps.auth", "true");

    props.put("mail.imaps.port", hunterPort);
    props.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port", hunterPort);

    props.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.quitwait", "false");

    return props;
}
}
```

i call it like:
    public class MailHandler {
    private static final String TAG = MailHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    private Activity activity;
    private MailSender mailSender;

```
public MailHandler(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void mail(Mail mail) {

    mailSender = new MailSender("oscar@*****-***.com", "*******");

    mailSender.setTo(mail.getTo());
    mailSender.setFrom(mail.getFrom());
    mailSender.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
    mailSender.setBody(mail.getBody());

    instantMailTask instantMailTask = new instantMailTask();
    instantMailTask.execute();

}


private class instantMailTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Bitmap, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ReceiptHandler receiptHandler = new ReceiptHandler(activity);

        //TODO get company name and contact info programmatically

        String body = "Hunter - CRM \n";
        body += receiptHandler.createReceiptLines();
        body += "\n contact" +
                "\n info" +
                "\n address";

        generateNote("Receipt", body);

        generateNote(MobileRegisterApplication.getActiveReceipt().getReceiptName(), receiptHandler.createReceiptLines());

        Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute: ");
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: ");


        try {
        mailSender.addAttachment(activity.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/Receipt.txt", "TryOut.txt");

            if(mailSender.send()) {
                Log.d("Mail", "doInBackground: Email was sent successfully.");
            } else {
                Log.d("Mail", "doInBackground: Email was not sent.");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        Log.d("Mail", "onPostExecute: ");

    }
}

public void generateNote(String sFileName, String sBody) {
    try {
        File root = new File(activity.getFilesDir(), "Receipts");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = activity.openFileOutput( sFileName +".txt",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        out.write(sBody);
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

Comment: IMAP is for retrieving mails, not for sending. A simple search would've shown this.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen. Thanks, thought so already, but had a college saying otherwise

Comment: Some servers, but this is rare, implement a special mailbox that will send emails that are placed there.  This is completely nonstandard though.  Generally, IMAP is fetch, SMTP is send.